# initial size BasicDataSource

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I configure my dataSource:

```
 <bean id ="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:openshifturl"/>
     <property name="username" value="username"/>
     <property name="password" value="pass"/>
     <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
     <property name="initialSize" value="5"/> 
 </bean>
```

and get the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [EntityOperatorBean.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'initialSize' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'initialSize' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

When I remove initialSize property all become to be OK. Why I  get this problem?

Comment: What version of DBCP are you using? `initialSize` was added in 1.2.

Comment: I'm using 1.4 version

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Is it possible that there is an older version somewhere on the server classpath? Can you try to change your dependency to `provided` and check whether you will get `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: to PROVIDED - what do you mean? to 1.2?

Comment: `<dependency><groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId><artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId><version>1.4</version><scope>provided</scope></dependency>`

Comment: I already use this dependency in my pom.xml. What is my next step?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33588/discussion-between-pavel-horal-and-lesya-makhova)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavel make me understand, that my Tomcat Server has strange dependency to dbcp 1.2. This can be because at first I created dependency to dbcp 1.2. And when I add later dependency to 1.4 it doesn't work.

I solve this problem by deleting my current Tomcat server and creationg the new one. Just radical method, but I solve my problem.